# Swift segue from CollectionViewCell failing to display new view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to simply load up a new view when a cell in my `CollectionView` is selected.

Everywhere online says it's as simple as registering a new view and a navigation controller in the storyboard, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click dragging from my `CollectionViewCell` to the new view.

Having done this, the code compiles and runs, but no new view appears when I click on my cells. What have I missed?

The storyboard says there is a segue from `CollectionView` to my next view (identified with the correct name and all), so I'm a bit confused...

Edit: here is my `CollectionView` controller code, in case I've done something in here that's causing the problem. It's a calendar page (as you can probably tell from the code):

```
IBOutlet weak var calendarCollection: UICollectionView!
var collectionView: UICollectionView?
let calendarCellIdentifier: String = "calendarCell"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView!.dataSource = self
    collectionView!.delegate = self
    collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: calendarCellIdentifier)
    collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.view.addSubview(collectionView!)
}

// Return the collectionView cell at IndexPath
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(calendarCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return challengeDurationDays
}
```

Comment: Check whether you have really created the segue from the cell and not from the view itself. You can check that by clicking the circle of the segue. If the cell becomes highlighted the segue is correct. If the whole view becomes highlighted, the segue isn't correct.

Comment: The cell highlights, so that's not it. My code builds and runs, it just doesn't do anything when I click on a cell.

Comment: I assume that your segue is a push segue. If so, is the view controller embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: I have a `Navigation Controller` in my storyboard, which in the layout viewer has a connection to the view controller.  The Collection View also has a `Navigation Item` in its hierarchy tree. That seems like it's embedded properly?

Comment: Yes. So, this isn't the cause as well. Something else: Does is work when you change the segue type to modal?

Comment: Still nothing I'm afraid.

Comment: In Xcode go to `View > Debug Area > Show Debug Area`. What do you see there when you click the cell?

Comment: Nothing, both when I click on the cell in storyboard or in the iPhone simulator.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar troubles with a CollectionView (using Xcode 6.1.1 for an iOS 8 app).  I setup a segue in my storyboard from the selection of the `CollectionViewCell` to another `ViewController`, but it would not work automatically when the cell was touched.  Further, I subclassed the `CollectionViewCell`, set the class of the cell in my storyboard to my custom class (`MazeCollectionViewCell`), and established `IBOutlets` in my class connected to an image and a label I placed in the storyboard cell.  However, when I tried to access the image and/or label in the `collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath` method, they were nil.

All my problems were solved when I **removed** the `registerClass` call from my viewDidLoad method [in my case, I removed `collectionView!.registerClass(MazeCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)`].  That's it!

My *guess* is that the `registerClass` call caused the `CollectionViewController` to create a blank copy of the class I specified and to ignore the template in the storyboard (thus my segue and my outlet connections were not valid in the cells being created for the collection).

If anyone has further insight, I'd love to hear it, but that's the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with similar problems, I solved this by manually triggering the segue using the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method.  I don't think I should have had to do this, but perhaps I misunderstood.  Either that or it's a bug.  The method I added to `CollectionViewController` in the end looks like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("dayViewSegue", sender: calendarCollection)
}
```